# Cognos report studio group for subtotals

Tags: cognos

I have this report which is grouped by column cities. when I add a total to the amount field, it doesn't display subtotals for each city... just a grand total at the end.

How do I add a subtotal row in Cognos report studio?

Answer (score 8):

You got a simple list and dragged the columns into it, which you want to group by and the data you want to sum up. In my example here I used "Shop", the "year" and the "sales volume":

[image]

Now you select the first column, in my example "Shop" and click on the button I marked red in the screenshot:

[image]

Do the same for the second column, in my example "Jahr / Year".

After that, click on the column which holds the data you want to measure, in my example "sales volume / AuftragGesamt" and click on the button with the sum symbol. Then you can choose how to aggregate the data.

[image]

As you can see multiple rows were added. You got a row under each shop, holding the sum for each shop. And finally at the very bottom you have a row holding the sum for all shops.

Comment: It looks to me like if you only group one column, the Cognos will only add a grand total.  But if you group two columns, then add a sum, you will get subtotals.  Then you can ungroup the other column and the subtotal remains.