# Cognos 10 Group Subtotal not showing

Tags: cognos-10

I have a list that shows columns from a query that is the result of a join (EmpJobs).

[image]

The list is grouped by Division and Department columns. When I highlight the Emp ID column and click Data -> Summarize -> Count in the toolbar, summary rows show up for Division and Overall, but I'm not getting a subtotal row for Department:

[image: Subtotal Missing]

However, when I have a list that shows columns from a query that is NOT the result of a join (the Employees Query above), I get the subtotal rows on Department like I expect:

[image]

Our system was recently switched from Cognos 8 to Cognos 10. I didn't run into this issue in version 8, so did something change in version 10? Conceptually? A new setting somewhere?

**Note:** Not sure if this applies, but I found [this post](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2013/04/cognos-incorrect-subtotalgrand-total.html), which describes a different issue, but he says that his problem happens to the result of a join, which is the case in my problem. I played with the "Auto Group and Summarize" settings as he did, but without success.

**Note 2:** I think my question is the same as ([Cognos report studio group for subtotals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114757/cognos-report-studio-group-for-subtotals)), but I don't think there was enough detail in the question to get the answer that the poster was looking for (no responses are marked as the answer). I follow the steps given in the one response, and I am still missing my subtotal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen before in Cognos 10. I believe it's a bug. However, I don't know if it's 10 specific as it's been years since I've worked with 8. There is a workaround available.

Access the 'List Headers & Footers' dialog box. This can be done in two ways:

1. Click on the 'Headers & Footers' button in the toolbar [image: Header & Footer Button] and select 'List Headers & Footers'
2. Select Headers & Footers>List Headers & Footers... from the Structure menu

This will bring up the following dialog box:

[image]

Tick the box next to 'Department (footer)' highlighted above and click OK.

You should now have a Department summary row with empty cells underneath your columns.

Unlock the report and drag over your summary item from your query, Count(Emp ID), and put it in the empty cell at the intersection of the new Department footer and the Employee ID column.

Comment: I will add that I needed to unmerge the cells in the footer that was created. The footer first showed as a giant merged cell. Also, unlocking the page is at: Structure menu -> Lock Page Objects. I don't do this very often so I had forgotten how.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. @Johnsonium: When you say you have seen this happen before, do you mean occasionally? Because my issue seems to happen consistently with lists that are the result of joins

Comment: No. It happens consistently. In the very simple test report that I created to get the images I observed the behavior. Since I knew the workaround I hadn't put much thought into the circumstances that caused it. You are correct. It's tied to the join. It's a Cognos bug for sure.